# How to get the html document as string in android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, html-parsing

In my code. I want to get the generated source code (html document) on the time of loading a web page. The function onPageFinished() i have written view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"); for getting the code but it shows the error "[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input", source:  (1)".
The web page is displaying correctly
I want to get the source code webpage. What is the way to retrieve source code and display it? How it possible?

My code is shown below:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.webkit.WebSettings;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;



 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView web1;
EditText ed1;
Button bt1;
String Address;
String add;
ProgressBar pbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    web1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    bt1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    pbar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Address = "http://" + ed1.getText().toString();
            WebSettings webSetting = web1.getSettings();
            webSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

            web1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            web1.loadUrl(Address);

        }
    });
}

public class WebViewClient extends android.webkit.WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        pbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML");
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web1.canGoBack()) {
        web1.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the text from a webpage like this then do as you want to:

```
public class HTMLPageDownloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        public static interface HTMLPageDownloaderListener {
            public abstract void completionCallBack(String html);
        }
        public HTMLPageDownloaderListener listener;
        public String link;
        public HTMLPageDownloader (String aLink, HTMLPageDownloaderListener aListener) {
            listener = aListener;
            link = aLink;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(link);
            String html = "";
            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                InputStream in;
                in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    str.append(line);
                }
                in.close();
                html = str.toString();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return html;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (!isCancelled()) {
                listener.completionCallBack(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to rewrite the source code and run in browser. For example i want to detect phone number in web page and then highlight the phone numbers by rewriting the code (like skype click to call). Is it possible in this code?

Comment: I dont get exactly what your purpose is,can you elaborate further.

Comment: In my browser, when i enter the url of a web site. when the page loaded, The page must be rewrite or redesign the html code. (In skype click to call function it may detect the phone numbers in the page and redesign the phone numbers in the page). Is it clear?

Comment: you mean you want phone numbers with a call popup whenever the curser appears above it.

Comment: yes. I want to detect the phone numbers of loaded web page. And a call popup whenever the curser appears above it.

Comment: **Linkify** is what I think you need.It is a helper class that creates hyperlinks within Text View (and Text View-derived) classes through RegEx(or Regular Expressions)pattern matching.
Text that matches a specified RegEx pattern will be converted into a clickable hyperlink that implicitly fires startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)),using the matched text as the target URI.Please visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

Comment: Did Linkify is working for web pages in my customized browser?